# Apple Watch re-paired, how do I re-import my ".watchface" file that I backed up?

Tags: apple-watch

I have a Series 2 Apple Watch (Nike) and a first-gen iPhone SE. My watch performance had been noticeably degraded recently, so I thought maybe I'd try unpairing and restoring it. I use iCloud backup.

I even had a suspicion about losing my photo so before I unpaired, I "shared" it to my MacBook via airdrop. There is now a `Photos.watchface` file in my Downloads folder.

After the restoration, I went back to the Photos watchface, but my photo was gone. I have no idea if it's even in my library anywhere, I took it many years ago and I think I even recall taking it in some fashion that put it exclusively on my watch and nowhere else. Regardless, I certainly can't find it in my photos.

What is this `.watchface` file, and how can I get my photo back on my watch? I would really like my watch to just be 100% back to the way it was, minus the performance issues - hopefully.